# Windows License Validity after Restoration from Backup of Other Machine

Tags: windows-7, backup, license

I am working to restore 30 or so company PCs from a single "clean" backup image. They all came with Windows 7 Pro, and have product key stickers on the cases.

On the first machine, I formatted the disk, installed the OS and a few essentials, and then used software to make an image of the machine.
 I'm using the same software to clone the image onto freshly formatted drives in the other machines.

They are booting fine, and Windows says that it is activated on each machine. I don't have an option to change the license, so am I to assume that they are using the correct license?

Comment: You should simply use the command to switch the license.  There is also a command to display the license in a command prompt if I am not mistaken.  There is always [ShowKeyPlus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus/releases/tag/ShowkeyPlus) nice little program that display your Windows key for you.  *You should verify each machine is using a different license.*

Comment: @Ramhound - If they're using the OEM license they will all show up as using the same license.

Comment: @JoeTaylor They are all showing up as the same license. Is there any way I would know if something is invalid?

Comment: @JoeTaylor Additionally, the license they are all showing does not match the license on the case of the machine I made the image of, nor of any of the other cases.

Comment: @michaelbmorris - So issue the command prompt command to change the license to the key on the machine for one of them.

Comment: @michaelbmorris - the SLP key is not tied to the COA Sticker, that sticker only shows you have a license if you return the box to the OEM for repair / reinstallation. The SLP key is a Generic Key so will show the same on all boxes assuming they are all from the same manufacturer. - This site explains it well: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/492736-all-our-dell-computers-reporting-the-same-windows-7-product-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine they are using the OEM license. This is automatically licensed using SLP so your copies of Windows are showing up as activated.
 The SLP key is not tied to the COA Sticker, that sticker only shows you have a license if you return the box to the OEM for repair / re-installation. The SLP key is a Generic Key so will show the same on all boxes assuming they are all from the same manufacturer.

For more information have a look [here](https://techdoors.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/activating-windows-7-oem-way/)